# Finding Connected Flights from my Airline database for more than two intermediate routes

Tags: sql, database-design, oracle10g

I am currently working on a academic miniproject for booking flight ticket between source and destination.

My Relational database table for Flight_table is

```
(flight_id,flight_date,flight_name,f_source,f_dest,f_available_seats)
```

where `(flight_id + flight_date)` is my primary key.

If `seats available = 0` for journey abc->pqr then I must look for connecting flight. For one intermediate stop I thought of simple self join like

```
SELECT a.flight_name , a.f_source, a.f_dest, b.flight_name, b.f_source, b.f_dest
FROM FLIGHT_TABLE a, FLIGHT_TABLE b
WHERE a.source = 'abc' AND a.f_dest = b.f_source AND b.f_dest = 'pqr'
AND (some date related condition)
```

Can someone help me to write efficient query if there are two or more intermediate stops (flights)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @FutbolFan : i will be using oracle 10g for it....

Comment: I have create tables and insert statements stored for all sample data in a file.. Please tell me how should i provide it to you...

Comment: Please use http://sqlfiddle.com/ or add it to the question above.

Comment: you can find them at https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1hVFn0wAn_ifnBxYXUzMGtQUXdicmRyaVNuNXFRNmQ1UEdralVuamR3MEV2MUpjTXNfWmc&usp=sharing

Comment: Your sample data is completely different than what you described in your question. Maybe you need to look into `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm

Answer (score -1):

Why you do not maintain a separate table or a view which can serve the purpose? where table or view may have the data to the self join without the input the condition. you may then query on the available data.

Comment: can you please suggest me how to create such a view or table when there are multiple connected flights in between...because there can be single/ two/ three connected flights in between.. how do store details of such variable no of flight details in a single view...?